# Powershell invoke WebRequest with NTLM for a post

Tags: rest, powershell, ntlm

### INITIAL QUESTION

How Can I perform Invoke-WebRequest or similar, with Powershell so that NTLM authentication is used but also supply a body for a post.

### EXAMPLE

The code sample below is my example post using invoke web request and pipes response out to a .json file. Username and Password Variable not included in example.

```
$myURL = https://example.blah.etc
$params = @" {""EXAMPLE1":"STUFF"} "@ 

$Headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password))) }


Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myURL  -Headers $Headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body  $params  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content > "C:\output.json"
```

### UPDATE

Using -UseDefaultCredentials only works for Gets, not for posts.

---

---

### ERROR RESPONSE

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Comment: There has been some work to improve the web request cmdlets in version 6.0. See thread here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4274 and documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-6

Comment: `Using -UseDefaultCredentials only works for Gets, not for posts.` -- You can perform NTLM-auth with GET, save the session to a variable (use `-SessionVariable`) and then do POST using saved session.

Answer (score 16):

Just use `-UseDefaultCredentials`.

Trying to manipulate the headers for NTLM is hard work.  It is a challenge response that is painful.  Let PS do the work...

Comment: That was the first thing I tried - it doesn't work when performing a post, only works for gets.

Comment: Have you tried removing the basic auth header? that is probably confusing the server.